# For $p \in (0,\infty)$, is it possible to have a function $f \in L_q$ for $q\neq p$ and $f \notin L_p$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

That is, is it possible for a function to be in all $L_p$ spaces except for a single value of $p \in (0,\infty)$?

For $p=1$ $q \in (1,\infty)$, an example would be
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
\frac1x \text{ if }x\geq 1\\
0 \text{ if }x< 1
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}

This example wouldn't work for values of $p,q\in (0,1)$ though.

Comment: Your example is not correct. Also, this question is a duplicate. Can you locate it on MSE?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I couldn't locate a duplicate of this same question. The ones I found were in the other direction where $f\in L_p$ for one value of $p$ but $f\notin L_q$ for $q\neq p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible: Suppose $f\ge 0,$ $q_1<p<q_2,$ and $f$ is in both $L^{q_1}, L^{q_2}.$ Then

$$\int_{f\le 1} f^p \le \int_{f\le 1} f^{q_1} <\infty$$

and

$$\int_{f>1 } f^p \le \int_{f\le 1} f^{q_2} <\infty,$$

proving $f\in L^p.$