# $L^{p_1}(X,\mu) \cap L^{p_3}(X,\mu) \subset L^{p_2}(X,\mu)$ for $1 \le p_1 \lt p_2 \lt p_3 \le \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\sum,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $1 \le p_1 \lt p_2 \lt p_3 \le \infty$. Show that $L^{p_1}(X,\mu) \cap L^{p_3}(X,\mu) \subset L^{p_2}(X,\mu)$.

---

From Holder's Inequality we know that for $1 \le p \lt q \le \infty$ that $L^q(X,\mu) \subset L^p(X,\mu)$.

Thus, $L^{p_3}(X,\mu) \subset L^{p_1}(X,\mu) \implies L^{p_3}(X,\mu) \cap L^{p_1}(X,\mu) \subset L^{p_1}(X,\mu)$. But from the statement above, since $ 1 \le p_1 \lt p_2 \lt \infty$ we should have that $L^{p_2}(X,\mu) \subset L^{p_1}(X,\mu) \implies  L^{p_2}(X,\mu) \subset L^{p_3}(X,\mu) \cap L^{p_1}(X,\mu)$. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What does $\Sigma$ mean ?

Comment: $L^q(X, \mu) \subset L^p(X, \mu)$ is only true if $\mu(X) < +\infty$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905227/for-p-in-0-infty-is-it-possible-to-have-a-function-f-in-l-q-for-q-neq/3905382#3905382

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Proposition } $(Interpolation inequality):  If $ (X,\Sigma,\mu) $ is a measurable space, $ 1 \leq p \leq q \leq \infty $ and $ f \in L_p(X) \cap L_q(X) $, then $ f \in L_r(X)  $ for all $ p \leq r \leq q $.

$\textbf{Proof}:$
First assume that $ q = \infty $. If  $ t=\frac{p}{r} $, then   $ |f|^r \leq ||f||_{\infty}^{r-p} |f|^p $. Hence,
$$ ||f||_r  \leq ||f||_{\infty}^{1-\frac{p}{r}} ||f||_p^{\frac{p}{r}} < \infty .$$
Now assume that $ q< \infty $. Let $t \in [0,1]$ such that
$$1= \frac{tr}{p}+\frac{(1-t)r}{q} .$$ Consider the conjugate exponents
$ p/(tr) $ and $ q/((1-t)r) $. By Holder's inequality, it follows that
$$ ||f||_r^r = \int |f|^r = \int |f| ^{tr} |f|^{(1-t)r} \leq ||f||_p^{tr} ||f||_q^{(1-t)r} < \infty.$$